# passing 2d array to function using pointers in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

this is first time I've had to ask a question here usually don't need but this time i just can't figure it out.
Basically i'm trying to create a grid in the console of 1s and 0s (1s and 0s in random places). the 1s being wood chips and 0s representing blank space. 
to do this i have to use this function which initializes and populates a 2d array and returns the pointer to the finished array

```
int* createEnvironment(int width, int height, int numWoodChips)
```

i then then need to print the 2d array using this function

```
void printEvrionment(int* environment, int width, int height)
```

this is what i have so far

```
int enviroWidth = 20;
int enviroHeight = 20;
int* createEnvironment(int width, int height, int numWoodChips);
void printEvrionment(int* environment, int width, int height);
void freeArray(int width, int* environment);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int *arr = createEnvironment(enviroWidth, enviroHeight, 10);
printEvrionment(arr, enviroWidth, enviroHeight);

getchar();
freeArray(enviroHeight, arr);
return 0;
}

int* createEnvironment(int width, int height, int numWoodChips)
{
int Num = 1;
/*randNum = (rand() % 1) + 0;*/
int temp = 3;
int woodChipCounter = 0;
int counter = 0;
int *array;
array = malloc(sizeof(array)*height *width);



for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == temp)
        {
            array[j*width + i] = 1;
            temp++;
            woodChipCounter++;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            array[j*width + i] = 0;
        }

        if (woodChipCounter == numWoodChips)
        {
            Num = 0;
        }
    }
}
return array;
}

void printEvrionment(int* environment, int width, int height)
{
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", environment[j]);

    }
}
}

void freeArray(int height, int* environment)
{
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    free(environment[i]);
}
free(environment);
}
```

Comment: Use `sizeof(*array)` in your malloc; not `sizeof(array)`. And your `freeArray` and `printEnvironment` both appear to have originally been centered around a *pointer* array, which is not what your code is allocating.

Comment: so, what's the question?

Comment: Should be `printf("%d ", environment[j * width + i]);`

Comment: Also, lose the loop in `freeArray`. There is only one call to `malloc` so you only need one `free`.

Comment: _this is first time I've had to ask a question here_ You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: @WhozCraig that is what i thought as i haven't really used C before and only java i did what came natural

Comment: `randNum = (rand() % 1) + 0;`, haha, nice one. I recommend `... & 1` instead, or just `... % 2` to keep it more reader-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int enviroWidth = 20;
int enviroHeight = 20;

char *createEnvironment(int width, int height, int numWoodChips);
void printEvrionment(char *environment, int width, int height);
//void freeArray(int width, int* environment);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *arr = createEnvironment(enviroWidth, enviroHeight, 10);

    printEvrionment(arr, enviroWidth, enviroHeight);

    getchar();
    //freeArray(enviroHeight, arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

char *createEnvironment(int width, int height, int numWoodChips){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int len = width * height;
    char *array = malloc(len);

    if(numWoodChips > len)
        numWoodChips = len;

    memset(array, '1', numWoodChips);
    memset(array + numWoodChips, '0', len - numWoodChips);

    for(int i=0;i<numWoodChips; ++i){
        char tmp;
        int pos = rand()%len;
        //swap array[i] and array[pos]
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[pos];
        array[pos] = tmp;
    }

    return array;
}

void printEvrionment(char *environment, int width, int height){
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j){
        for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i){
            printf("%c", environment[width * j + i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i change that to integers as memset is chars only

Comment: @user3476732 I think that is changing to an integer and not difficult, but i seem to be sufficient in the char.